# asXML destroy xml file?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Hi I have a problem about asXML function in php. Assume I have a xml file which named xml_file and have below content.

```
<employees>
  <employee>
    <name>Mark</name>
    <age>27</age>
    <salary></salary>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <name>Jack</name>
    <age>25</age>
    <salary>$4000</salary>
  </employee>
</employees>
```

I wrote this code for change a variable in my xml file.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($xml_file));
$xml->employee[1]->name = 'David';
$xml->asXML($xml_file) or die ("asXML failed.\n");
```

And my problem is that since first salary tag is empty asXML function destroy this tag and it outputs like that

```
<employees>
  <employee>
    <name>Mark</name>
    <age>27</age>
    <salary/>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <name>David</name>
    <age>25</age>
    <salary>$4000</salary>
  </employee>
</employees>
```

How can I prevent that? Thanks for any proper solutions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XML :-

```
<salary></salary> = <salary/>  <-- both are empty tag
```

Comment: To expand on this a bit: The two are completely equivalent. If you have software which accepts `<salary></salary>` and not `<salary/>`, **then it is broken and you should not be using it to parse XML**.